# Difficulty with files in a C database

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h> //for the clear screen function
 #include <string.h>

 void load_menu(void);
 void customers_menu(void);
 void createNew(void); //initialize your file
 void addRecord(c c1[30]); //add a new record to the file
 FILE *fp;

 struct customer
 {
     int custID;
     char custName[50];
     char custAddress[100];
 };

 typedef struct customer c;


 int main(void)
 {

    load_menu();
 return 0;
 }

 void load_menu(void)
 {
int choice;

do
{
    printf("Customer Orders Main Menu. \n\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: \n");
    printf("1. Customer's Menu \n");
    printf("2. \n");
    printf("3. \n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("\n");
    if (scanf("%d",&choice)==1)
    {

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: system ("cls");
                    customers_menu();
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 2: system ("cls");
                    
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 3: system ("cls");
                   
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 4: printf("Quitting program!\n");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice! Please try again\n");
                    printf("\n");
                break;
        }
     }

    else
     {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Characters are invalid, please enter a number: \n ");
        choice=0;
     }

}while((choice !=4));
}




  void createNew(void)
  {
    File *fp;
    fp=fopen("Customer.dat", "r");
    if (fp==NULL)
        printf("File creation failed! \n");
    else
       printf("File created! \n");
    fclose(fp);
 }

void add_Customer (c c1[30])
 {
   int i, n , cc=0;
   FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen("Customer.dat", "a");
   system("cls");

   if(fp==NULL)
   {
       printf("File Creation Failed!");
   }
   system("cls");

   printf("Enter the number of Customers: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
   {
       printf("Customer's ID (numbers only)  : ");
       scanf("%d", &c1[i].custID);

       printf("Customer's  Name              : ");
       gets(c1[i].custName);

       printf("Customer's Address            : ");
       gets(c1[i].custAddress);



       fwrite(&c1[i], sizeof(c), 1, fp);
   }cc++;

   fclose(fp);
 }

  void recordCount(c c1[30], int *count)
 {
   addRecord(c1);
   count=0;
   count++;
 }

  void customers_menu(void)
  {
int choice;
    c c1[30];
     int i;

    createNew();
do
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Customers Menu \n\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: \n");
    printf("1. Add Customer \n");
    printf("2.\n");
    printf("3.\n");
    printf("4. Go back to Main Menu \n");
    recordCount (c1, &i);

    if (scanf("%d",&choice)==1)
    {

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: add_Customer(c1);
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 2:
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 3:
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 4: printf("Going back to Main Menu\n");
                    system ("cls");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice! Please try again\n");
                    printf("\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Characters are invalid, please enter a number: \n ");
        choice=0;
    }

}while((choice !=4));
 }
```

I have a problem with the files as I am new to C and we were only given one month to learn it and do this assignment about it so if you can help me with the files issue I would really appreciate because I don't know how to work with them , I just tried my best to attempt this code

Comment: What is the difficulty/problem?

Comment: No question. First impressions if it is a file problem is that Customer.dat is not in the output directory. Other than that we cannot offer directions if you do not offer information.

Comment: void addRecord(c c1[30]); //add a new record to the file
Here it is giving me an unknown type name C and File *fp; is giving me an error of unknow type name File

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile errors

   - addRecord() implementation is missing
   - typedef of c needs to be made before using it.
   - File *fp needs to be replaced by FILE *fp
2. Other problems

   - createNew() sounds as if you want to create a new file "Customer.dat", while access mode "r" opens an existing file for reading. Use "w" as access mode for creating a new file.
   - of course you should only call fclose(fp) if the prior fopen() call was successfull.
   - add_Customer() adds one more customer than desired (replace <= with < in the for loop)

and so on. I don't believe that the list is complete...

Comment: I arranged them thanks a lot but still the Add customer function is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

1. `void addRecord(c c1[30]);` needs to be after your typedef declaration of type `c`, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `c` is.
2. File needs to be replaced with uppercase `FILE`.
3. Provide an implementation for `addRecord()` otherwise it's unresolved.